# Can you replicate a normal table to a system versioned temporal table?

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2016, temporal-tables

I'm curious to know whether I can replicate a table in SQL Server where the publisher is a normal table, and the subscriber is a system versioned temporal table? Is that possible?

The intent is to have a DW containing the historical (and current) data of an ODS. The DW being the subscriber, and the ODS being the publisher in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an explanation from the [online docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-table-considerations-and-limitations).

Snapshot and transactional replication: Only supported for a single publisher without temporal being enabled and one subscriber with temporal enabled. In this case, the publisher is used for an OLTP workload while subscriber serves for offloading reporting (including `AS OF` querying).